# How to fix this to write a program that uses while loops to calculate the first n Fibonacci numbers

Tags: c++, while-loop, fibonacci, do-while

I am new to C++ programming and I am a bit lost.  Here is what I am suppose to do and my code.  Any ideas on what to do?

Write a program that uses while loops to calculate the first n Fibonacci numbers. Recall from math the following definition of the Fibonacci sequence:

> The Fibonacci numbers Fn are defined as follows. F0 is 1, F1 is 1 and Fi+2 = Fi + Fi+1 for i = 0, 1, 2, ... . In other words, each number is the sum of the previous two numbers. The first few Fibonacci numbers are 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, and 13.

The program should prompt the user for n (the number of Fibonacci numbers) and print the result to the screen. If the user enters an invalid value for n (n <= 0), print an error message and ask the user to re-enter n (an input validation loop for n). This MUST be a loop, not an if statement like Lab 2.

The output should be similar to the following:

Enter the number of Fibonacci numbers to compute: 3
The first 3 Fibonacci numbers are:
1 1 2

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int f0 = 0, f1  = 1,f2= 2, i = 0, n;
    cout << "Enter the number of Fibonacci numbers to compute: ";
    cin >> n;
    if ( n <= 0)
    {
        cout <<"Error: Enter a positive number: ";
        return 1;
    }
    while ( i < n){
        f2 = f0 + f1;
        i++;
    }

    cout << "The first " << n << " Fibonacci numbers are: " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, this is critical code for their new cloud-based social networking and derivatives trading app.

Comment: @David: Considering that remarks like "... not an if statement like Lab 2." have been left in, it might well be.

Comment: @Orbling: duh, not sure how I missed that :(

Comment: Doesn't fibonacci use recursion normally? I see nothing of the sort here.

Comment: Honestly yes it is.  It's just that I've been working on this since last night and I still can't figure it out.

Comment: IN the text book it has an example of recursion but we are not on that chapter yet and therefore cannot use it yet.

Comment: @Luis: Homework isn't absolutely objected to here - though people like to see it a) stated, and b) see what progress you've made, so they can guide, rather than tell.

Comment: f2 = f0 + f1; is going to give you f2 with a value of 1 after your while loop finishes. You didn't do any updates to f0, f1 or f2, neither did you try to store the result in an array in each loop. How are you going to get any results? And also why f0 initialise to 0 ?

Comment: You don't use recursion for fibonacci numbers; such an approach has a remarkably high time complexity.

Comment: @avakar You do if your teacher says to:-)  For various reasons, calculating fibonacci numbers is a classical introduction to recursion.  (Perhaps not the best: in general, if the state you need to maintain has a small upper bound, recursion isn't a good solution.)

Comment: @JamesKanze, is it? I thought the canonical introduction was the factorial. :) (Which in real life you wouldn't write recursively either, but at least the recursive version of factorial retains the linear time complexity of the iterative version.)

Comment: @avakar Maybe.  Both tend to show up a lot when introducing recursion (despite both having a very small upper bound on the state needed to be saved).

Answer (score 2):

```
 while ( i < n){
        f2 = f0 + f1;
        i++;
    }
```

See this loop, this is where the problem is, since this is homework, i'll not tell exactly what the problem is, take a pen and paper, and start executing your statements, specially this loop, you'll find your error. Just a hint, Fibonacci number is the sum of previous two fibonacci numbers.

Comment: thank you I will try it and let you know soon if it worked. once again thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You got the `f2=f0+f1` right. However, you should note that when you increment `i`, then `f2` becomes `f1` and `f1` becomes `f0`.

If you name them like this, it would make more sense:

```
int f_i_minus_2 = 0, f_i_minus_1 = 1, f_i;
```

and you would have

```
f_i = f_i_minus_1+f_i_minus_2;
```

Now, imagine `i` is 3. You have written:

```
f[3] = f[2]+f[1]
```

When you increment `i`, you must have:

```
f[4] = f[3]+f[2]
```

That is `f_i` is put in the place of `f_i_minus_1` and `f_i_minus_1` is put in the place of `f_i_minus_2`.

(Look at this:

```
f[3] = f[2] + f[1]
 |       |
  \_____  \____
        \      \
f[4] = f[3] + f[2]
```

)

So you need two assignments after computing `f_i`:

```
f_i_minus_2 = f_i_minus_1;
f_i_minus_1 = f_i;
```

Note that I first changed `f_i_minus_2` to `f_i_minus_1` because the second assignment destroys the value of `f_i_minus_1`.

Comment: just by looking at your answer, yes it makes sense, let's see what happens when I try fixing it. Thank you

Comment: Another unrelated note is that in the end of your program, instead of printing `f_i`, you are saying `cin >> n` which tries to read a number for `n` which doesn't make sense.

Comment: If you want to just print the values, you can print it in the same loop you compute it. If you want to have them stored somewhere, you should first `new` enough memory, then fill the memory by setting `arr[0] = 0;` and `arr[1] = 1;` then going over i (from `2` to `n`) and setting `arr[i] = arr[i-1]+arr[i-2];` which doesn't need the trick I told you, because you are already moving forwards in the array. To print it, then, you need another `for` that goes over the array and prints the values one by one.

Answer (score 0):

According to wikipedia, your definition is off. F0=0, F1=1, F2=1, F3=2, ...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number

Assuming wikipedia is right your loop is basically

```
int i = 0, f, fprev;
while( i < n )
{
    if( i == 0 )
    {
        f = 0;
        fprev = 0;
    }
    else if( i == 1 )
    {
        f = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        int fnew = f + fprev;
        fprev = f;
        f = fnew;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested, there are [better ways to calculate it](https://www.nayuki.io/page/fast-fibonacci-algorithms).

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, since you never modify `f0` and `f1` in the 
loop, `f2` isn't going to depend on the number of times through the
loop.  Since you have to output all of the numbers at the end anyway,
why not try keeping them in an array.  I'd initialize the first two
values manually, then loop until I had enough values.

(This can be done quite nicely using the STL:

```
//  After having read n...
std::vector<int> results( 2, 1 );
while ( results.size() < n )
    results.push_back( *(results.end() - 1) + *(results.end() - 2));
```

I'm not sure that this is what your instructor is looking for, however.
I rather suspect that he wants you to to some indexing yourself.  Just
remember that if you initialize the first two values manually, your
index must start at 2, not at 0.)

Another thing: the specification you post says that you should loop if
the user enters an illegal value.  This is actually a little tricky: if
the user enters something that isn't an `int` (say "abc"), then 1)
`std::cin` will remain in error state (and all further input will fail)
until cleared (by calling `std::cin.clear()`), and the illegal
characters will not be extracted from the stream, so your next attempt
will fail until you remove them.  (I'd suggest `>>`ing into an
`std::string` for this; that will remove everything until the next white
space.)  And don't **ever** access the variable you `>>`ed into until
you've checked the stream for failure—if the input fails.  If the
input fails, the variable being input is not modified.  If, as here, you
haven't initialized it, then anything can happen.

Finally (and I'm sure this goes beyond your assignment), you really do
need to do something to check for overflow.  Beyond a certain point,
your output will become more or less random; it's better to stop and
output that you're giving up in this case.